# Jboss EAP 6.3 and Spring boot 1.5.2 - deployment starup issue with logback

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss7.x

Environment:
 - Spring Boot 1.5.2 (war)
 - java 1.7
 - jboss EAP 6.3

**I am stuck with following error while running spring boot application war on jboss EAP:**

Same [issue](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1265) listed here but did not mention what to do with Jboss EAP 6.3.

Appreciate your help!

`17:48:22,682 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-13) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."basp.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."basp.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "basp.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018104: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: logback-classic-1.1.11.jar
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadSci(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:210)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:131)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018104: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: logback-classic-1.1.11.jar
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadSci(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:202)
    ... 7 more`
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: # See javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer javadocs from [Module "deployment.basp.war:main" from Service Module Loader]**

    `at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadSci(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:194)
    ... 7 more`

**Dependencies as following:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Why do you need JBOSS if you have Spring Boot?  Run as an executable JAR and leave Java EE behind.  Where is the Spring Boot starter parent?  Your Maven pom.xml is missing a dependency.

Comment: @duffymo 1)Our Production environment forces us to use Jboss. I have worked with Spring boot deployments also. I know how it feels to coming back to jboss for a spring boot project. 2) Starter parent is there. I am able to build it. infact ran with Jboss 7 EAP successfully however Due Production imposed constraint we need to use jboss EAP 6.3. 3) yes I missed one dependency javaee6 api thats a typo. I will update it.

Answer (score 1):

Including this and many other issues followed this I have captured into  [Spring boot and Jboss Integration](https://programmingthoughtworkbysrinivasan.blogspot.in/2017/04/spring-152-with-jpa-21-integration-with.html)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: specify logback version in your `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <logback.version>1.1.9</logback.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1265.

You have to upgrade (or downgrade) logback.